# Uploading to specified target with jQuery fileupload?

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I'm using [jQuery fileupload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) on a site to upload a single file for processing.  I've got a simple upload working based on the Basic Plus demo, but would like to upload files to a given path *and filename* on the server (independent of the filename on the client machine).  It seems like this should be straightforward, but I'm having problems figuring it out or finding resources. Is this possible in jQuery fileupload?  If so, can anybody point me in the right direction for how?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Answered? Found some helpful information [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/622#issuecomment-4278885) on changing the filename of uploads.